# Transforming LPP into transportation matrix

Tags: linear-programming, network-flow

I need to transform an LPP into a transportation matrix, however, where I would expect greater than' for constraints on demand, the LPP only has 'less-than' constraints. Any hints on transforming this to a transportation problem.[image]'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduce nonnegative slack variables to convert each constraint to an equality.  For example, introduce $x_{14}\ge 0$ and replace the first constraint with $x_{11}+x_{12}+x_{13}+x_{14}=13$.  Now interpret the slack variables $x_{i4}$ as flow variables into a dummy destination node and the slack variables $x_{3j}$ as flow variables from a dummy source node.  Also introduce $x_{34}\ge 0$ to make the bipartite graph complete.  The corresponding transportation matrix is $3 \times 4$, and the new entries all have $0$ cost.